# Filtering a large table by date

Tags: sql, performance, date, join, hive

I have a table, VISIT_INFO, with these columns:

```
pers_key - unique identifyer for each person
pers_name - name of person
visit_date - date at which they visited a business
```

And another table, VALID_DATES, with these columns:

```
condition - string
start_date - date
end_date - date
```

I currently have the following query:

```
select pers_key, pers_name from VISIT_INFO a
CROSS JOIN
(select start_date, end_date from VALID_DATES where condition = 'condition1') b
WHERE (a.visit_date >= b.start_date and a.visit_date <= b.end_date)
GROUP BY a.pers_key
```

So 'condition1' has a specific start_date and end_date. I need to filter VISIT_INFO for visits that are between the two dates. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. From my current understanding, it currently has to go through the entire table (millions of rows) and add start_date and end_date to each row. Then does it have to go through each row again and test against the WHERE condition?

I ask this because when I remove the cross join and hardcode the start_date and end_date for condition1, it takes substantially less time. I'm trying to avoid hardcoding in the dates because it will lead to serious tedium down the road.

So to reiterate, is there a better way to filter VISIT_INFO by specific dates in VALID_DATES?

Edit: I just realized I left out a pretty huge piece of information, being that this is all in HIVE. So EXISTS and joins on (a between b and c) are out of the question.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is almost never the right answer.

Comment: Can you offer a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pers_key, pers_name
FROM visit_info
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM valid_dates
    WHERE condition = 'condition1'
    AND visit_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
);
```

?

Comment: Any idea how I would achieve something like this in HIVE? I accidentally left the fact I was using hive out of the question body.

Comment: What version of Hive are you running?  Hive starting 0.13 should support subqueries in the `WHERE` clause, as well as `EXISTS`.  For `EXISTS`, you need a correlated subquery, but my example is correlated.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

Comment: I'm running .12, which is probably why it's giving me an error. "Cannot recognize input near "select" "1" "from" in function specified". @Tripp Kinetics

Answer (score 0):

```
with dt as (select start_date, end_date from VALID_DATES where condition = 'condition1')
select a.pers_key, a.pers_name 
from VISIT_INFO a
JOIN dt on a.visit_date between dt.start_date and dt.end_date
GROUP BY a.pers_key
```

Comment: Does this need a join to the CTE?

Comment: `join dt  on a.visit_date between dt.start_date and dt.end_date` ?

Comment: modified it @JamieD77

Answer (score 0):

Trying the `exists` version is definitely a possibility.  However, you might be better off expanding the `VALID_DATES` table, so there is one row per date.

Then, the query:

```
select vi.*
from VISIT_INFO vi JOIN
     VALID_DATES_expanded vde
     ON vi.visit_date = vde.valid_date
where vde.condition = 'condition1';
```

can make use of an index on `VISIT_INFO(visit_date)` and on `VALID_DATES_expanded(condition, valid_date)`.  This is likely to be the fastest approach to solving this problem, if `VISIT_INFO` is very large and relatively few rows are being selected by the query.

Comment: But then wouldn't this only be checking if visit_date was equal to a certain date, instead of checking if it is between two dates?

Comment: @Tarzan . . . The expanded table would have all dates between the two values.  Although the data is larger, an equi-join is much easier to optimize.