# Querying for dates listed in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I want to select certain rows of a table that are between two dates (which are found in a seperate table). The details of my tables and query can be found in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543811/filtering-a-large-table-by-date/31544197?noredirect=1#comment51062072_31544197) (I am now interested in how to do this in HIVE/hiveQL). As my current query stands, it runs for a long time then seems to hang indefinitely, whereas when I hardcode in the dates it runs to completion fairly quickly. Tables and Query for reference:

VISIT_INFO, with these columns:

```
pers_key - unique identifyer for each person
pers_name - name of person
visit_date - date at which they visited a business
```

VALID_DATES, with these columns:

```
condition - string
start_date - date
end_date - date
```

And the query itself:

```
select pers_key, pers_name from VISIT_INFO a
CROSS JOIN
(select start_date, end_date from VALID_DATES where condition = 'condition1') b
WHERE (a.visit_date >= b.start_date and a.visit_date <= b.end_date)
GROUP BY a.pers_key
```

Its worth noting Im using HIVE 0.12, so getting rid of the join and putting the select statement in the WHERE clause is out of the question. I'm wondering what exactly is wrong with this query, or what could be causing it to fail. Any suggestions as to how to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just added the info in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select pers_key, pers_name 
from VISIT_INFO a 
join 
valid_dates b
WHERE a.visit_date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
GROUP BY pers_key, pers_name;
```

As of Hive 0.13:

```
select pers_key, pers_name 
from VISIT_INFO a , valid_dates b
WHERE a.visit_date BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
GROUP BY pers_key, pers_name;
```

Comment: Each start_date and end_date in valid_dates correspond to a certain condition. I need to check if the visit_date is between the start_date and end_date for 'condition1'. Would I just add that into the where clause?

Comment: If the condition is required for a specific segmant to be returned in the query then you can add it to the where clause.  If your condition is something like a customer channel such as web, kiosk, counter, or phone you could add to the where clause to filter.  "Where condition in ('web','kiosk')".

Comment: @invokertheshell Awesome, that worked, thanks. Any idea as to why my original query took multiple hours and this took less than 20 minutes? I should mention VISIT_INFO is an extremely large table.

Comment: My query is an inner join while yours is a full outer join ( cartesian join).  Also, can you upvote my answer and choose as answer please.